# Find MAC addresses in /proc or somewhere despite bonding device?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

Is there a way to get the original MAC addresses for eth0 and eth1?

A large array of servers have bonding interfaces managing backup switch connections and one is misbehaving. With bond0 active both MAC addresses are replaced and reported identically by ifconfig.

I want to search the server array for a MAC address I found in a Cisco device.

I would use [dmesg(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) or /var/log/messages, but they have been rolled over for  hundreds of days for most of the array.

Comment: I think nobody else actually understood your question correctly, but I thing I do. I'll see if I can find something and report back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm still searching for a more "official" explanation, but according to [this blog](http://vaunaspada.babel.it/blog/?p=415), the file `/proc/net/bonding/${bonding name}` will provide the actual mac address for each NIC in the bond (eth0, eth1, etc..), so that might be more useful.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Here's where I would look for it

Answer (score 9):

On RHEL/CentOS 6:

```
# ethtool -P <if>

Permanent address: 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

Comment: This also works.

Answer (score 8):

You can get this from `/sys` instead of `/proc`. For example:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
0a:58:ac:16:05:13
```

All the interfaces available are listed under `net`:

```
$ ls /sys/class/net/
eth0  lo
```

Answer (score 3):

The OS should keep a list of physical NIC details within the file:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Here is mine as an example:

```
# This file maintains persistent names for network interfaces.
# See udev(7) for syntax.
#
# Entries are automatically added by the 75-persistent-net-generator.rules
# file; however you are also free to add your own entries.

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:23:54:95:74:e5", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

**Notice the "ATTR{address}==" section?**

Comment: This works also.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **arp** to find a MAC address

To find the manufactors MAC the IEEE Registration Authority keeps a list of brand names that belong and there MAC addresses, the first six in a MAC address are the brand name followed by type and serialnumber

[Search the Public OUI/'company_id' Listing](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html)

Comment: A bonded interface intentionally does not behave that way. The OP seems to be looking for the MAC address that was burned into the EEPROM of his physical hardware that is part of such bonded interface. This MAC exits the layer 2 stage when bonding is set up.

Answer (score -3):

dmesg | grep eth0 && dmesg | grep eth1

You can grab the reported hardware addresses for any interface prior to the bond being established.

Answer (score -3):

If you are not sure of the interface name (happens with CentOS 7) try:
 `ip addr`

and just pick the interface from the list

Comment: I get the impression you didn't actually read the question. It clearly states: *With bond0 active both MAC addresses are replaced and reported identically by ifconfig.*